# Upgrading RN 0.37 to 0.41 broke ability to run on device

Tags: xcode, react-native

So I upgraded to react native 0.41 and now when I run my app on a physical device (ipad pro) it looks pixelated and isn't full screen. It has black bars on the sides (iphone aspect ratio) and has a 1x button at the bottom right which i can tap to zoom out. I've been googling for an hour and the RN ecosystem moves so fast that google is useless in many cases.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly related to RN. Your app is probably set to run only on iPhone, not on iPad. Maybe it was reset when you upgraded.

An iPhone app that runs on an iPad is displayed in a special "compatibility mode" where you view it in a smaller iPhone-like viewport that you can zoom in and out (the x1 and x2 buttons you see).

If you want your iPhone app to also run natively on iPad:

1. open Xcode in the project navigator (left panel)
2. click the project file, then select your app target (will appear on the right side in the left pane under TARGETS once you select the project)
3. in the "General" tab, scroll to "Deployment info" settings and change the "Device" selector to "Universal".

Note that while it will run in native iPad resolution, if you're not optimizing your UI for larger screens, your existing UI will just stretch and fill up your whole screen.